# how to fetch data from a dynamically loading page using selenium webdriver javascripts

Tags: javascript, selenium

Please help me to rectify it.
this is my xpath: `//*[starts-with(@id,'highcharts')]/svg/g[7]/g/g/g[1]/text` but its not working.

`//*[starts-with(@id,'highcharts')]` but this one is working fine.

I need to fetch data from 'text' from page (its a graph label which is dynamically loading).

`//*[starts-with(@id,'highcharts')]` using this i can select the entire graph frame but I need to get particular data from graph.

when I tried in this way it throws error `//*[starts-with(@id,'highcharts')]/svg/g[7]/g/g/g[1]/text`

Comment: please share your full code or interface link from where you are trying to get text data.

Comment: Please Share the HTML code snippet and What youre trying to Highlight. Also if this site is publcily available please share the Link.